# Stopping Clustered Index script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index, kill-process

I have a loooooong running script that us generating a clustered index on a 77M row - 20GB table.

I need to query this data so I want to stop the Index Generation and resume it in the night.

Is it OK to `KILL` the `ProcessId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server should respond just fine to killing any process. However, it might take a while to cleanup after itself. For instance, if you kill a big update query, it will have to roll-back the transaction. For in index build, it should not have such problems and should return relatively quick. Point is, as long as you let the kill finish without doing something drastic like powering down, you should be fine.

Comment: +1 A clustered index build rollback might take a while though

Comment: @ChrisShain The whole reason for me to `KILL` is so I can access the data.  With the `ROLLBACK`, I will end up spending time that I might as well have spent on creating the index. I guess I'm learning a real good lesson here - create Clustered Index at the right time.

Comment: @DonDickinson This isn't a regular index - it's `clustered`

Comment: @RajMore Thats what I figured, which is why I mentioned it. Best way to create clustered index by ***far*** is to create a new table with the same structure and the index defined, BCP the data out of the old table (in the same order as the clustered index, if possible), and then BCP it into the new table.

Answer (score 3):

Killing the PID will cause the transaction to roll back.

It shouldn't hurt to do, but the rollback is going to be painful.

There is no way to pause it and continue later where you left off.